# Randomly copy certain amount of certain file type from one directory into another

Tags: command-line, cp, random

Sometimes I have a folder full of jpg's and I need to randomly choose 8 or so of them. How could I automate this so my account randomly chooses 8 jpg's from the folder and copies them to another destination?

My question is simple really, instead of using `cp` and giving it a file name then destination file name, I want to build a script that randomly chooses 8 of the .jpgs in the folder, and copies those to another folder.

Comment: you can use a combination of crontab and mv.

Answer (score 42):

You could use `shuf`:

```
shuf -zn8 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 cp -vt target/
```

- `shuf` shuffles the list of `*.jpg` files in the current directory.
- `-z` is to zero-terminate each line, so that files with special characters are treated correctly.
- `-n8` exits `shuf` after 8 files.
- `xargs -0` reads the input delimited by a null character (from `shuf -z`) and runs `cp`.
- `-v` is to print every copy verbosely.
- `-t` is to specify the target directory.

Comment: What if some of the file names start with `-`? I tried `shuf -zn8 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 cp -vt -- {} target/` to no avail.

Comment: For anyone who has found this answer and has seen @havakok's question, they also asked the question here and obtained an answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544902/372726

Comment: This solution does not work with a large number of files. Halavus answer solves the problem in that case.

Answer (score 8):

The best answer absolutely didn't worked for me, because `-e *.jpg`  doesn't actually look into the working directory. It's just an expression. So `shuf` doesn't shuffle anything...

I found the following improvement based on what I learned in that post.

```
find /some/dir/ -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 shuf -e -n 8 -z | xargs -0 cp -vt /target/dir/
```

Comment: The `-e *.jpg` expects a set of matching files in the current directory. If there are no matches it will (usually) return the single literal  `*.jpg` to `shuf`, which then has only one element to consider.

Comment: Thank you for this solution; it works with a large number of files, as opposed to the accepted solution.

Comment: If you are on *MacOS*, first install coreutils for the shuf command (`brew install coreutils`), then use: `find /some/dir/ -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 shuf -e -n 8 -z | xargs -0 -J % cp -v % /your/target/dir`

Comment: For me it is the best answer because for a huge directory with thousand of images, the @chaos answer fails

Comment: At least on Macos 12.6, `xargs` will execute the `shuf` for every 5000 items of input. So you may easily get more than you'd expect using this method.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with Python.

Here is a python scscript I use to move a random percent of images that also gets associated label datasets typically required for CV image datasets. Note this moves the files because I do not want my test training dataset in my training dataset.

I use the below for Yolo training sets as labels and images are in the same directory and the labels are txt files.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random

#set directories
directory = str('/MauiData/maui_complete_sf_train')
target_directory = str('/MauiData/maui_complete_sf_test')
data_set_percent_size = float(0.07)

#print(os.listdir(directory))

# list all files in dir that are an image
files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.jpg')]

#print(files)

# select a percent of the files randomly 
random_files = random.sample(files, int(len(files)*data_set_percent_size))
#random_files = np.random.choice(files, int(len(files)*data_set_percent_size))

#print(random_files)

# move the randomly selected images by renaming directory 

for random_file_name in random_files:      
    #print(directory+'/'+random_file_name)
    #print(target_directory+'/'+random_file_name)
    os.rename(directory+'/'+random_file_name, target_directory+'/'+random_file_name)
    continue

# move the relevant labels for the randomly selected images

for image_labels in random_files:
    # strip extension and add .txt to find corellating label file then rename directory. 
    os.rename(directory+'/'+(os.path.splitext(image_labels)[0]+'.txt'), target_directory+'/'+(os.path.splitext(image_labels)[0]+'.txt'))

    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve files in this way:

```
files=(/tmp/*.jpg)
n=${#files[@]}
file_to_retrieve="${files[RANDOM % n]}"
cp $file_to_retrieve <destination>
```

make a loop 8 times.

Comment: So essentially rather than an answer you provide a list of variable names.