# Coping with filenames starting with a dash ("-") when using `-exec` and `xargs`

Tags: command-line, cp, xargs, exec

I am following [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217712) though some of the file names here contain a dash at the beginning of the filename. This is interpreted as an additional option for `cp`.

Following [another question (on ServerFault)](https://serverfault.com/questions/462739), I tried altering the command to:

```
shuf -zn8 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 cp -vt -- {} target/
```

or

```
shuf -zn8 -e *.jpg -exec cp -vt -- {} target/
```

to no avail. How do I cope with `-` at the beginning of the filename?

Comment: Related: [What does "--" (double-dash) mean? (also known as "bare double dash")](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376) [Why do I need the double dash before argument passed to sh by xargs -I for it to work properly?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/85635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-t` option (a GNU extension) takes an argument which is the target directory.

With `xargs -0 cp -vt -- target/`, that would try to copy `target/` and the selected files into a directory called `--`, and you would still not have marked the end of options. You would need to mark the end of options for `shuf` as well.

`{}` is only special with `find`'s `-exec` predicate, or with `xargs` if you use `-I'{}'`, but you don't need it here. `shuf` has no `-exec` predicate.

Here, you'd want:

```
shuf -zen8 -- *.jpg | xargs -r0 cp -vt target --
```

Or

```
shuf -zen8 ./*.jpg | xargs -r0 cp -vt target
```

With `zsh`, you can also use its `e`xpression-based `o`rdering glob qualifier:

```
cp -v -- *.jpg(oe['REPLY=$RANDOM'][1,8]) target/
```

That has the advantage over the `shuf` approach to work on any system (provided `zsh` is installed; you may need to give up on the non-standard `-v` on some systems) and also to still work even if there are two many `jpg` files in the current directory (and executing `shuf` would fail with a *Too many arguments* error).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's `shuf` not `cp` which is struggling with the filenames beginning with a dash. Try adding the double-dash to the `shuf` command:

```
shuf -zn8 -e -- *.jpg | xargs -0I{} cp -vt -- "{}" target/
```

I'd use `find` for this, rather than `shuf`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0I{} cp "{}" target/
```

Also you don't need to double-dash for `cp` in this case as `find` will return the filename with `./` prefixed.

Comment: Will `find` copy random files or the first files?

Comment: ah okay maybe use `shuf` if you want them to be random